# Magento Getting Fatal error with custom module

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I am getting following error : 
**Class 'Lucky_Test_Helper_Data' not found in E:\wamp\www\raj\magento_new\app\Mage.php on line 521**

I created this module using module creator.
I checked it with one of my magento installation, it worked fine. Then I copied the module to the actually installation where I wanted to use it.

I did a some debugging, and found that if I comment certain part of **config.xml** I get no error.

I figured that out after having a look at stack trace of error, which included following line.
**include( 'E:\wamp\www\raj\magento_new\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\menu.phtml' );**

here is my **config.xml**

now if I comment :

```
    <!--<test module="test">
    <title>Test</title>
    <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
    <children>
    <items module="test">
    <title>Manage Test </title>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <action>test/adminhtml_test</action>
    </items>
    </children>
    </test>-->
```

I get no error. Module seems to be loading fine till this point. 
Do you see anything wrong?
Help me out.

Comment: Do you have a Lucky_Test_Helper_Data class inside of Data.php in your module's Helper/ directory?

Comment: yes, I do have the class, even, when I paste the module, tables are created, and it stops while creating the menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly define that you are using helpers, like this:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <test>
            <class>Lucky_Test_Helper</class>
        </test>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

In the menu you define with `module="test"` that your module handles the translation for it

Comment: I wish I could upload the complete **config.xml** code here. yes, I've defined it like this, <br />`<global>
        <helpers>
            <test>
                <class>Lucky_Test_Helper</class>
            </test>
        </helpers>`
but, it is not working, and as I said, when the module is loaded (or being loaded), it's related tables are created in database. and menu is defined this way : `<test module="test"> .... </test>`

Comment: You can post it to the services like pastebin.com and alike

Comment: yes, I did clear cache after changes, I even deleted items manually from cache folder, I know, that is not advised, but, I did that...

Comment: Seems to be all good to me. Where is your helper file located? Can you put it to the pastebin too?

Comment: out of ideas... try removing module="test" from menu nodes. if this doesn't help archive whole module so I can take a closer look

Comment: Ok, thanks for your quick response. I will do as you suggested, and in case that does not work, I'll send you the archived code of the module...

Comment: I made couple of changes in my config.xml, took example of modules that were working, cleared cache couple of time, and and and it worked, I am also out of ideas why it was not working earlier, and why it worked this time... :(

Comment: @RavishTiwari Magento could be weird at times, but the more you get to know it the less mysteries it will have for you. Just like any other complex system. Good luck with development!

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is my first ever project in Magento, and I am running into problem every now and then, but, with each solved problem, I am gaining more confidence, and thanks to geeks like you and stack overflow, I am so far doing good with it :)